# Client javascript for Action Cable Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, frameworks, actioncable

In websocket-rails of rails 4 I use the client framework javascript below and works fine

```
var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('//ws:localhost:3000/websocket');
var channel    = dispatcher.subscribe('my_channel');

channel.bind('my_event', function (content) {
   console.log(content);
});
```

where ***new WebSocketRails(...)*** is a javascript framework than I found in Internet

This javascript framework WebSocketRails don't works with action cable of rails 5 because the implementation is different.

Somebody know any websocket javascript framework than works with action cable for listen channels specific?

I tested the native class from javascript Websocket() and it connect with websocket but haven't functions for "listen" channels.

Sorry for my bad English =)

Answer (score 3):

You can try [actioncable](https://yarnpkg.com/zh-Hans/package/actioncable) on Yarn or NPM which is published from Rails.

And this is my Vue js code:

```
import ActionCable from 'actioncable';

var cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable');

var channel = cable.subscriptions.create(
    'MyChannel',
    {
        connected: function() {
            console.log("connected");
        },
        disconnected: function() {
            console.log("disconnected");
        },
        received: function(data) {
            console.log('received');
            console.log(data);
        }
    }
);
```